# What is the best way to contribute to bringing Stack Exchange (especially AI, but everything code) to other languages?

Tags: discussion, localization, languages, inclusion-project

I'm active in AI governance and actually in a lecture recently Luisa Olaya was talking about the barriers to using AI in the developing world, and what a problem it was that there aren't tools to help local developers, even in Spanish. Lots of people talk about lack of data in local languages (as if AI just programs itself from data (hint: it doesn't really)). Anyone on Stack Exchange knows that actually providing real developer help is a big issue.

1. It wasn't initially obvious that there were existing projects like this, can we make the answers to this question somehow direct to the feedback that was in the "redundant question" response?
2. There are actually a lot of resources globally to this kind of problem, and endless new AI NLP tools. Is there something we could do help link efforts to SE?

Comment: I've added the link for proposing non-English sites to the duplicate list. Not because that one is particularly relevant or different from proposing a site in English, but because it links to [this post](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20988/178611), which states that since 2015, proposals for sites in other languages than English aren't accepted anymore. Perhaps that an existing community with funding and sponsorship is different though..

Comment: A Stack Overflow site for [Modern Standard Hindi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindi) may or may not help (320 million native speakers (590 million if L2 is included)).

Comment: Hindi & Spanish were the two languages we were thinking of. Showing my ignorance of the SE process here, but should we delete this question or leave it as a pointer? Because I didn't find the answer when I searched, and I'm *pretty* good at search.

Comment: It says I should edit the question or delete it, I edited it but it still says it's closed...

Comment: Welcome to Meta SE. Editing your question doesn't automatically reopen it. Instead, the *first* edit after a question is closed puts it into the [Reopen Review Queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) where it will be checked to see if it should be reopened. However, your question's [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/363166/timeline) shows it was edited about an hour ago by another user, but there then were 3 votes to leave it closed. Thus, your latest edit did not cause it to go to the reopen queue. That would need to be done by clicking on the Reopen link instead.

Comment: Hey Joanna! The links in the duplicate banner are shown to all users, so your question doesn't need answers to direct to those other questions and their answers (which seems to be the point of your first question). As for redirecting efforts to SE, it would probably help to include a few examples of specific efforts, to give an idea of what you were thinking to send this way. That sounds more like a new [tag:site-recommendation] question to me though, so perhaps ask a new one, instead of editing this one into a totally different question.